# Receiving Java Error - ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am receiving the following error in a Java program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (java.util.ArrayList$SubList and java.util.ArrayList are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Below is the method I am working with.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> dups(ArrayList<Integer> myList) {
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

            ArrayList<Integer> auxiliar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            auxiliar = (ArrayList<Integer>) myList.subList(i + 1, myList.size() - 1);

            if (auxiliar.contains(myList.get(i)) && !(duplicates.contains(myList.get(i)))) {
                duplicates.add(myList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return duplicates;
    } // End of method
```

What might be causing this? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code missed safe typing at a couple of spots.

I propose programming against *interfaces* instead of concrete classes. Use interface types for variables, and create, implement them using a concrete class, like `duplicates` below.

This way you may change the implementation later, and you write more powerfull methods. Now `subList` may be assigned to `auxiliary`.

```
public static List<Integer> dups(List<Integer> myList) {
    List<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> auxiliar = myList.subList(i + 1, myList.size() - 1);
        if (auxiliar.contains(myList.get(i)) && !duplicates.contains(myList.get(i)))) {
            duplicates.add(myList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return duplicates;
}
```

You could also use a `Set` for the duplicates. This would improve correctness; consider three same elements.

```
public static Set<Integer> dups(List<Integer> myList) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `subList()` method returns an object of the nested static class `ArrayList.SubList`. You are trying to cast it to `ArrayList`, although they are not related by inheritance, so `ArrayList.Sublist` can not be `ArrayList`. You can use e.g. `List<Integer>` as `ArrayList.SubList` implements interface `List<E>`.

Comment: "although they are not related by inheritance" this is not entirely correct. `List` is a superclass of `ArraList`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant like directly, so ```ArrayList.Subclass``` is not a child of ```ArrayList```.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) tells you that the method `subList()` returns a `List<E>`.

```java
public static List<Integer> dups(ArrayList<Integer> myList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        // you try to cast List<E> to ArrayList<Integer> which results in your error
        // auxiliar = (ArrayList<Integer>) myList.subList(i + 1, myList.size() - 1);
        List<Integer> auxiliar = myList.subList(i + 1, myList.size());

        if (auxiliar.contains(myList.get(i)) && !(duplicates.contains(myList.get(i)))) {
            duplicates.add(myList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return duplicates;
}
```

Additionally, avoid using raw types. If you use `ArrayList` without declaring a specific type e.g `ArrayList<Integer>` then you're using it raw.

*Hint:* It's always recommended to have a look at the documentation. E.g. in your code `myList.subList(i + 1, myList.size() - 1);` you don't have to subtract `1` from `size()`.

Documentation of `public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. ....